# Image large size

Tags: images

My website http://www.mixtalk.in/ uploaded feature images seen in extra large size which is not better please help

Comment: The system ask for the size of the featured image like thumbnail, medium, large, and full. So you need to select the size you need on the post. Normally I use large is the size is declared on my theme, but I use FULL is the image uploaded has the size I need inside the post, Ex 900x350

Answer (score 2):

Your css is doing it. Replace following css if not being used anywhere else. If you're not comfortable then ask your designer to do it

line 1213

```
.thumb-box {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

line 2321

```
.box img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   image-rendering: optimizequality;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: how to where it replace

Comment: Go to appearance > editor. Find above two css and replace them

Comment: Sir I have replace this code in line1213 and line 2321 but the problem is still same

Comment: try clearing your cache

Comment: I have another question

Comment: My website left top corner see a content "page contents" what is this, and why see it

Comment: page contents is coming from some file in your theme. i can't tell without seeing theme files. You can check header.php or functions.php

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please mark the question as answered. Thank you